# Android.runtime.javapropertyThrowable: system.collection.generic.keynotfoundexception

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting 'Key not found exception' occasionally When I open my application. I am not find what the cause of this exception in android. Here is the crash report I got in hockey app.[image]

Comment: Please show your code or refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563491/keynotfoundexception-info, it explains why the  `KeyNotFoundException`  happens in `Dictionary` in c#.

Comment: Hi, I am also getting similar exception. When I open my application it self I am getting this exception and it is happening very occasionally. Please suggest any idea.